# TFS 2015 Backlog Items Edit Item Field dropdown no longer populates after update 3

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

[Field dropdown no longer populates after update 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNPoJ.png)

Issue appeared after installing TFS 2015 update 3. As the image indicates (see link above), this issue occurs on the "Features" or "Backlog" items. The exact same Edit pop-up dropdown populates as expected from the iteration backlog link [populated dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYdn8.png). Multiple browsers were attempted, as was clearing caches, and disabling TFS plug-ins. Because the dropdowns correctly populate from the iteration backlog, its presumed that this is not a data related issue. This TFS server has been successfully operating for a number of years and through multiple TFS version upgrades.

Answer (score 2):

[This issue was also posted on MSDN forum here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a7317aee-5bf4-43a9-968b-593afd81ddf0/tfs-2015-after-update-3-backlog-edit-work-items-field-dropdown-no-longer-populates?forum=tfsadmin)
Where the issue was successfully reproduced and bug reporting was recommended.

[The bug was reported here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2850185/edit-work-items-field-dropdown-fails-to-populate-from-features-or-backlog-links-after-update-3-rc-applied)

Comment: Tested again for this issue. The issue did exist in new created PBI, but not existed in old PBI items. I should test both scenario, sorry. Reported on my side too.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested with Tfs2015.Update3.RC1, your issue is NOT reproducible. Please try with another browser or test on another machine.

[image]

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a7317aee-5bf4-43a9-968b-593afd81ddf0/tfs-2015-after-update-3-backlog-edit-work-items-field-dropdown-no-longer-populates?forum=tfsadmin#a7317aee-5bf4-43a9-968b-593afd81ddf0

Comment: Tested again for this issue. The issue did exist in new created PBI, but not existed in old PBI items. I should test both scenario, sorry. Reported on my side too.